# All my functions don't seem correct

Tags: jquery, html, css, json, ajax

I am posting a very broad question here and it might seem like quite a challenge to some people. But any help will be appreciated!

I am busy building a small web app that displays different news articles via AJAX and JSON.

I have made a search feature which also populates various posts based on the user input. The problem I am facing now is the Lazy Loading that I am trying to build. But I think the problem actually starts way before I even execute the Lazy Load function.

When I execute the `getposts` function when I reach 100 pixels above the bottom of the screen, my getposts function seems to append multiple times rather than just once with the new set of data.

More specifically the piece of code here -

```
//LAZY LOAD
$(function ($) {
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $(document).height() - 100) {
            getposts(str);
            changePage = '2';
        }
    });
});
```

This then gives me a result of more than one page being appended and I think it has something to do with the `getposts` function.

I hope that someone with a bit more knowledge could maybe take a look at my code, maybe sift through it and criticize what I have done wrong. Maybe suggest a better/the right way to do certain things.

My articles change with a onclick event and then other functions come into play to populate the content via Ajax and Jquery.

I would really appreciate any help you might give :)

Please, take a look at the code I have inserted below -

I have also inserted a link to one of my JSON files for you to test with -

And a link to the CSS file since it is pretty long -

```js
var newsData;
var eventsData;
var nightData;
var dineData;
var outData;
var videoData;
var data;
var str = 'news';
var changePage = '1';

function getposts(str) {
    var baseUrl = 'http://www.capetownetc.com/api/get_category_posts/?slug=';
    var pageCount = '&count=10&page=';
    
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET'
        , url: baseUrl + str + pageCount + changePage
        , data: {
            get_param: 'value'
        }
        , dataType: 'json'
        , success: function postData(data) {
            
            if (str == 'news') {
                newsData = data;
                displayPosts(newsData);
            }
            if (str == 'events') {
                eventsData = data;
            }
            if (str == 'nightlife%20culture') {
                nightData = data;
            }
            if (str == 'dine') {
                dineData = data;
            }
            if (str == 'family%20fun') {
                outData = data;
            }
            if (str == 'videos') {
                videoData = data;
            }
        }
    });
}
getposts('news');
getposts('events');
getposts('nightlife%20culture');
getposts('dine');
getposts('family%20fun');
getposts('videos');

function displayPosts(str) {
    data = str;
    if (str == 'news') {
        data = newsData;
    }
    if (str == 'events') {
        data = eventsData;
    }
    if (str == 'nightlife%20culture') {
        data = nightData;
    }
    if (str == 'dine') {
        data = dineData;
    }
    if (str == 'family%20fun') {
        data = outData;
    }
    if (str == 'videos') {
        data = videoData;
    }
    var maxLength2 = 6;
    var maxLength = 130;
    var imgTitle = {};
    var imgThumb = {};
    var cat = {};
    var ex = {};
    var text = {};
    var time = {};
//    $('#post-cont').empty();
    
    $("#post-cont").append('<div class="ip1 full-post-img" id="card" attr-index="0"><div class="ip1 full-post-info"><a class="ip1 post-cat">Breaking News</a><h2 class="ip1 text-heading" id="ip1Heading">' + data.posts[0].title + '</h2><p class="ip1 post-source" id="ip1Source">' + data.posts[0].date + '</p></div><span class="ip1 main-card-img1" id="ip1img"></span></div>');
    
    $('#ip1img').css('background-image', 'url(' + data.posts[0].thumbnail_images.medium.url + ')');

    $.each(data.posts, function (i, item) {
        
        //TITLE
        imgTitle = item.title.replace('Newsflash:', '');
        console.log(imgTitle);
        
        //THUMBNAIL
        imgThumb = item.thumbnail_images.medium.url;
        
        //CATEGORY
        cat = item.categories[0].title;
        
        //EXCERPT
        ex = item.excerpt.substr(0, maxLength);
        
        //CONTENT
        text = item.content;
        
        //TIME
        time = item.date;
        
        if (i > 0){
         $("#post-cont").append('<div class="p full-post-text" id="card" attr-index="' + i +'"><div class="p1 text-post-img"><span class="p1 card-img1" id="p1Img" style="background-image:url(' + imgThumb + ');"></span><a class="p1 post-cat">' + cat + '</a> </div><div class="p1 full-text-info"><h2 class="p1 text-heading" id="p1Heading">' + imgTitle + '</h2>' + ex + '<p class="lay2 post-source">' + time + '</p></div></div>');   
        }
           
        //    POST POPULATE ***
    $(document).on('click', '#card', function(i, item) {
        $('#cont').css('left', '0px');
        $('#cont').css('position', 'relative');
        $('#cont').css('top', '0');
        $('#cont').css('display', 'block');
        $('#swipe').css('display', 'none');
        $('#post-header').css('left', '0px');
        $('#post-cont').css('left', '-9999px');
        $('#slider').css('left', '-9999px');
        $('#slider').css('display', 'none');
        
        $(window).scrollTop(0, 0);
        
        var ind = $(this).attr("attr-index");
        imgTitle = data.posts[ind].title;
        
        imgThumb = data.posts[ind].thumbnail_images.full.url;
        
        text = data.posts[ind].content;
        
        var maxLength2 = 6;
        time = data.posts[ind].date.substr(10, maxLength2);
        
        $('#cont').html('<div class="content-container"><div class="header-img"><span id="para-img"></span></div><div class="pageContent"><h1 class="post1 header">' + imgTitle + '</h1><p class="lay2 post-source">' + time + '</p>' + text + '<div class="post inter-tags"><ul class="post-tag-list" id="post-inter-tags"></ul></div></div></div>');
        
        $('#para-img').css('background-image','url(' + imgThumb + ')');
        
        $.each(data.posts, function (key, value) {
            var cat = data.posts[ind].tags[key].title;
            var apCat = '<li><input type="checkbox" id="tagPol" value=" " class="tag"><label             for="tagPol" class="inter-label">' + cat + '</label></li>';
            $('#post-inter-tags').append(apCat);
        });
        
    });
        
    });
    
} //End of displayPosts

//LAZY LOAD
$(function ($) {
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $(document).height() - 100) {
            getposts(str);
            changePage = '2';
        }
    });
});

//SEARCH FUNCTION
$('#sLoad').css('opacity', '0');
$("#search-btn").click(function (e) {
    var userText = $.trim($('#searchArea').val());
    $('.full-post-img').css('display', 'none');
    $('.full-post-text').css('display', 'none');
    $('#op').attr('checked', false);
    $.getJSON('http://www.capetownetc.com/api/get_search_results/?search=' + userText, {
        srsearch: userText
        , action: "query"
        , list: "search"
        , format: "json"
    , }, function (data) {
        if (userText.length === 0) {
            $("body").append("<p class='results'>Please enter a keyword</p>");
            $('#sLoad').css('opacity', '0');
        }
        else {
            $("#swipe").empty();
            var imgTitle = {};
            var imgThumb = {};
            var cat = {};
            var ex = {};
            var time = {};
            var maxLength = 130;
            var maxLength2 = 6;
            $.each(data.posts, function (i, item) {
                imgTitle = item.title.replace('Newsflash:', '');
                console.log(imgTitle);

                //THUMBNAIL CHECK
                if (item.thumbnail_images) {
                    imgThumb = item.thumbnail_images.full.url;
                }
                else {
                    imgThumb = item.thumbnail;
                }
                
                //CATERGORY
                if (item.categories[0]) {
                    cat = item.categories[0].title;
                }
                else {
                    cat = 'Blog';
                }
                //EXCERPT
                ex = item.excerpt.substr(0, maxLength);
                
                //TIME
                time = item.date;

                $("#swipe").append('<div class="p full-post-text" id="search-result" attr-index="' + i +'"><div class="p1 text-post-img"><span class="p1 card-img1" id="p1Img" style="background-image:url(' + imgThumb + ');"></span><a class="p1 post-cat">' + cat + '</a> </div><div class="p1 full-text-info"><h2 class="p1 text-heading" id="p1Heading">' + imgTitle + '</h2>' + ex + '<p class="lay2 post-source">' + time + '</p></div></div>');
                
                $(document).on('click', '#search-result', function(i, item) {
                    $('#cont').css('left', '0px');
                    $('#cont').css('position', 'relative');
                    $('#cont').css('top', '0');
                    $('#cont').css('display', 'block');
                    $('#swipe').css('display', 'none');
                    $('#post-header').css('left', '0px');
                    $('#post-cont').css('left', '-9999px');
                    $('#slider').css('left', '-9999px');
                    $('#slider').css('display', 'none');

                    $(window).scrollTop(0, 0);

                    var ind = $(this).attr("attr-index");
                    imgTitle = data.posts[ind].title;

                    imgThumb = data.posts[ind].thumbnail_images.full.url;

                    text = data.posts[ind].content;

                    time = data.posts[ind].date.substr(10, maxLength2);

                    $('#cont').html('<div class="content-container"><div class="header-img"><span id="para-img"></span></div><div class="pageContent"><h1 class="post1 header">' + imgTitle + '</h1><p class="lay2 post-source">' + time + '</p>' + text + '<div class="post inter-tags"><ul class="post-tag-list" id="post-inter-tags"></ul></div></div></div>');

                    $('#para-img').css('background-image','url(' + imgThumb + ')');

                    $.each(data.posts, function (key, value) {
                        var cat = data.posts[ind].tags[key].title;
                        var apCat = '<li><input type="checkbox" id="tagPol" value=" " class="tag"><label             for="tagPol" class="inter-label">' + cat + '</label></li>';
                        $('#post-inter-tags').append(apCat);
                    });

                });
                
            });
        }
        //SEARCH SUCCESS
        $('#sLoad').css('opacity', '0');
        $('#results').css('display', 'inline-block');
        $('#search-img').css('display', 'none');
        $('#iSlider').css('display', 'none');
        $('#searchBR').css('display', 'block');
    });
});

$('textarea').keydown(function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#search-btn").click();
    }
});

$('#searchBR').click(function () {
    $('#swipe').html('<div class="post-cont" id="post-cont"><div class="ip1 full-post-img"><a class="link-click" id="post1"></a><div class="ip1 full-post-info"> <a class="ip1 post-cat">Breaking News</a><h2 class="ip1 text-heading" id="ip1Heading"></h2><p class="ip1 post-source" id="ip1Source"> / </p></div><span class="ip1 main-card-img1" id="ip1img"></span></div><div class="p1 full-post-text"><a class="p1 link-click" id="post2" target="_blank"></a><div class="p1 text-post-img"><span class="p1 card-img1" id="p1Img"></span><a class="p1 post-cat">Sport</a></div><div class="p1 full-text-info"><h2 class="p1 text-heading" id="p1Heading"></h2><p class="p1 text-post-desc" id="p1Desc"></p><p class="p1 post-source" id="p1Source"> / </p></div></div><div class="p2 full-post-text"><a class="p2 link-click" id="post3" target="_blank"></a><div class="p2 text-post-img"><span class="p2 card-img2" id="p2Img"></span><a class="p2 post-cat">Local News</a> </div><div class="p2 full-text-info"><h2 class="p2 text-heading" id="p2Heading"></h2><p class="p2 text-post-desc" id="p2Desc"></p><p class="p2 post-source" id="p2Source"> / </p></div></div><div class="p3 full-post-text"><a class="p3 link-click" id="post4" target="_blank"></a><div class="p3 text-post-img"><span class="p3 card-img3" id="p3Img"></span><a class="p3 post-cat">Health</a> </div><div class="p3 full-text-info"><h2 class="p3 text-heading" id="p3Heading"></h2><p class="p3 text-post-desc" id="p3Desc"></p><p class="p3 post-source" id="p3Source"> / </p></div></div></div>');
    displayPosts(str);
    $('#searchBR').css('display', 'none');
    $('#results').css('display', 'none');
    $('#iSlider').css('display', 'inline-block');
    $('#search-img').css('display', 'inline-block');
    $('#op').attr('checked', false);
});
$('#searchB').click(function () {
    $('#results').css('display', 'none');
    $('#searchArea').val('');
});
$("#search-btn").click(function () {
    $('#sLoad').css('opacity', '1');
});

        //***PROBLEM AREA***

//GET CATEGORIES
var catNames = {};

function getAllCat() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET'
        , url: 'http://www.capetownetc.com/api/get_category_index/'
        , data: {
            get_param: 'value'
        }
        , dataType: 'json'
        , success: function (data) {
            $.each(data.categories, function (key, item) {
                catNames[key] = item.title;
                $('#tag-list').append('<li><input type="checkbox" id="tagPol" value=" " class="tag"><label for="tagPol" class="inter-label">' + catNames[key] + '</label></li>');
            });
        }
    });
}
getAllCat();

//    SWIPE EVENT ****
$('#swipe').bind('swipeleft', function () {
    if (str == 'news') {
        displayPosts('events');
        str = 'events';
        $(".i-item.current").removeClass("current");
        $('.interest-list li:nth-child(2) p').addClass("current");
    }
    else if (str === 'events') {
        displayPosts('nightlife%20culture');
        str = 'nightlife%20culture';
        $(".i-item.current").removeClass("current");
        $('.interest-list li:nth-child(3) p').addClass("current");
    }
    else if (str === 'nightlife%20culture') {
        displayPosts('dine');
        str = 'dine';
        $(".i-item.current").removeClass("current");
        $('.interest-list li:nth-child(4) p').addClass("current");
        if ($(window).width() < 370) {
            $('#interestSlider').animate({
                scrollLeft: 330
            }, 600);
        }
        else {
            $('#interestSlider').animate({
                scrollLeft: 260
            }, 600);
        }
    }
    else if (str === 'dine') {
        displayPosts('family%20fun');
        str = 'family%20fun';
        $(".i-item.current").removeClass("current");
        $('.interest-list li:nth-child(5) p').addClass("current");
        if ($(window).width() < 370) {
            $('#interestSlider').animate({
                scrollLeft: 330
            }, 600);
        }
        else {
            $('#interestSlider').animate({
                scrollLeft: 260
            }, 600);
        }
    }
    else if (str === 'family%20fun') {
        displayPosts('videos');
        str = 'videos';
        $(".i-item.current").removeClass("current");
        $('.interest-list li:nth-child(6) p').addClass("current");
    }
    console.log(str);
});
$('#swipe').bind('swiperight', function () {
    if (str == 'events') {
        displayPosts('news');
        str = 'news';
        $(".i-item.current").removeClass("current");
        $('.interest-list li:nth-child(1) p').addClass("current");
    }
    else if (str === 'nightlife%20culture') {
        displayPosts('events');
        str = 'events';
        $(".i-item.current").removeClass("current");
        $('.interest-list li:nth-child(2) p').addClass("current");
        if ($(window).width() < 370) {
            $('#interestSlider').animate({
                scrollLeft: -330
            }, 600);
        }
        else {
            $('#interestSlider').animate({
                scrollLeft: -250
            }, 600);
        }
    }
    else if (str === 'dine') {
        displayPosts('nightlife%20culture');
        str = 'nightlife%20culture';
        $(".i-item.current").removeClass("current");
        $('.interest-list li:nth-child(3) p').addClass("current");
        if ($(window).width() < 370) {
            $('#interestSlider').animate({
                scrollLeft: -330
            }, 600);
        }
        else {
            $('#interestSlider').animate({
                scrollLeft: -250
            }, 600);
        }
    }
    else if (str === 'family%20fun') {
        displayPosts('dine');
        str = 'dine';
        $(".i-item.current").removeClass("current");
        $('.interest-list li:nth-child(4) p').addClass("current");
    }
    else if (str === 'videos') {
        displayPosts('family%20fun');
        str = 'family%20fun';
        $(".i-item.current").removeClass("current");
        $('.interest-list li:nth-child(5) p').addClass("current");
    }
});

//Making current styles for interest slider
$('.i-item').click(function () {
    if (!$(this).hasClass("current")) {
        $(".i-item.current").removeClass("current");
        $(this).addClass("current");
    }
});

//POST PAGE BACK BUTTON
$('.back').click(function () {
    $('#cont').css('left', '-9999px');
    $('#cont').css('display', 'none');
    $('#post-cont').css('left', '0px');
    $('.interest-slider').css('left', '0px');
    $('#swipe').css('display', 'block');
    $('#post-header').css('left', '-9999px');
    $('iframe').attr('src', '');
});

//LOADING SCREEN
$(document).ajaxComplete(function () {
    $("#loading").delay(1000).fadeOut("slow");
});

//INTEREST MENU OPTION
$('.interests').click(function () {
    $('.inter-cont').css('left', '0px');
});

//INTEREST MENU OPTION - BACK
$('.interLogo').click(function () {
    $('.inter-cont').css('left', '-9999px');
});

//Parallax on post page
$(window).scroll(function () {
    var scrolledY = $(window).scrollTop();
    $('#para-img').css('background-position', 'center ' + ((scrolledY)) + 'px');
});
//$.each(data.categories, function(key, item){
//                catNames[key] = item.title;
//                $('#tag-list').append('<li><input type="checkbox" id="tagPol" value=" " class="tag"><label for="tagPol" class="inter-label">' + catNames[key] + '</label></li>');
//            });
//ANIMATE SEARCH RESULTS
//$("#searchR").hide();
//$('#searchArea').bind('input propertychange type', function() {
//    if (!$.trim($("#searchArea").val())) {
//       $("#searchR").hide(500);
//    }
//    else{
//     $("#searchR").show(500);   
//    }
//});
//    FOR LOOP TO GET ALL CATEGORIES
//        $.each(data.posts , function(key , value){ // First Level
//        $.each(value.tags , function(k , v ){  // The contents inside stars
//            $('#post-inter-tags').append('<li><input type="checkbox" id="tagPol" value=" " class="tag"><label             for="tagPol" class="inter-label">' + v.title + '</label></li>');
//        });     
//        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="iSlider" id="iSlider">
                    <ul class="interest-list" id="interestSlider">
                        <li><p onclick="displayPosts('news'); str = 'news'" class="i-item current">Home</p></li>
                        <li><p onclick="displayPosts('events'); str = 'events'" class="i-item">Events</p></li>
                        <li><p onclick="displayPosts('nightlife%20culture'); str = 'nightlife%20culture'" class="i-item">Nightlife</p></li>
                        <li><p onclick="displayPosts('dine'); str = 'dine'" class="i-item">Dine</p></li>
                        <li><p onclick="displayPosts('family%20fun'); str = 'family%20fun'" class="i-item">Outdoors</p></li>
                        <li><p onclick="displayPosts('videos'); str = 'videos'" class="i-item">Video</p></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
```

[JSON Data File](http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=03359737092332610289)
[CSS Stylesheet](http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=01390573000425238635)

Comment: See [mcve] please

Comment: Please be specific with your problem - _The problem I am facing now is the Lazy Loading that I am trying to build. But I think the problem actually starts way before I even execute the Lazy Load function._ : What is the problem you're having with your code? Any errors? How did you tried to solve it?

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply,  I will update the question.

Answer (score 0):

Like it says in the comment, please be specific with your problem.

But one thing that I see right away is that you are using the same name for the ids for checkboxes, don't do this, you should make sure it is unique. Where you are giving the id of tagpol, make it look like this to make it unique:

```
    $.each(data.posts, function(key, value) {
  var cat = data.posts[ind].tags[key].title;
  var apCat = '<li><input type="checkbox" id="tagPol' + key + '" value=" " class="tag"><label for="tagPol' + key + '" class="inter-label">' + cat + '</label></li>';
  $('#post-inter-tags').append(apCat);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Did that quick change. wasn't causing any problems, but still needed to be changed none the less.